# Differing results for Heckman 2-stage model between Stata and R

Tags: r, stata

I'm working on a project that requires me to run a Heckman 2-stage model, which is pretty new to me, using probit for both stages. As an empirical check I ran the model in both Stata and R. I'm running Stata 13 and R v. 3.2.3 with the "sampleSelection" package. The problem is that I'm getting differing results and I think it's because of my lack of understanding of the algorithms behind the code. Maybe I'm missing arguments. One thing that I know is that R is running a Tobit model for the second stage rather than probit. I'm wondering if someone might have some insight into how to get R to run the 2-stage model using probit methods for both stages. Below I've included the Stata code and results first then the R code with results.

#### Stata code

```
heckprob  ivburden  isingle recuse50 infobk2 timesurv inh icp itime igate ioth, 
select(iw5rsp= i201 isingle icatmpgte7 ichgfrwv inh icp itime igate     ioth)  vce(robust)
```

[image: STATA Output]

#### R code

```
library(sampleSelection)
heckit(selection = iw5rsp ~ i201 + isingle + icatmpgte7 + ichgfrwv + 
              inh + icp + itime + igate + ioth, 
          outcome = ivburden ~ isingle + recuse50 + infobk50 + timesurv + 
              inh + icp + itime + igate + ioth, data = dat, 
          method = "2step")
```

[image: R Output]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably good to start with the help pages for that package to see if the functions are doing what you think they are: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/sampleSelection.pdf

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a small sample of your data along with the stata and R output of the model code when run on the smaller data sample? To provide a data sample (for easy use in R) use `dput()`. For example, to provide the first 20 rows of your data, paste in the output of `dput(dat[1:20, ])`, and also the output of the stata and R models run with that data (or whatever data sample illustrates your issue and makes your question reproducible.

Comment: `tobit` and `probit` are the same?

Comment: @arvi, I did look at the package documentation and only found that the difference is the fact that the R package defaults to Tobit for the outcome regression. My hope was that someone might know how to set it to probit-probit, which I wasn't able to find in the documentation. Essentially I'm wondering if there's something creative that I can do to make the function return something similar to a probit function. It may be impossible.

Comment: @42, tobit is a bit different from probit in that Tobit is built more for ordinal, or polytomous, variables. The parameter is different in that rather than being bounded by 1 and 0 it's only got a lower bound of 0. I'm not 100% sure that it'll necessarily make the parameters different, but it seems different enough to me.

Comment: @eipi, unfortunatley I can't provide any of the data I used for that exact output because I'm working with confidential data. And, while I can generate some fake data, I'm not sure that it's worth it since my question is a conceptual one. I'm really trying to get at the difference between the R and Stata algorithms.

Comment: That's not a good description of my understanding of the difference between tobit and probit. My understanding is that tobit distributions are built on truncated Guassians while  probit models are based on untruncated ones. This only obliquely intersects with my area of interest, and I'm not at all knowledgeable on Stata methods.

Comment: I believe some of the confusion lies in that the maximum-likelihood probit model with sample selection is sometimes called a Type II Tobit, not to be confused with type I that's used for censored outcome data. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model#Variations_of_the_Tobit_model) for more.

Comment: @Dimitriy, thank you for pointing that out. It turns out that there are 5 types of Tobit regressions (I through V) and "sampleSelection" only has type II and type V, but what I need is type I since this is the one that is similar to a probit. It seems then that this package may just not do what I need it to do, which I think I have to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple solution that I missed because I did not notice that I did not express my dependent variables as inequalities. In the code that I posted in here you can see that there is no inequality symbol. I took a closer look at the documentation and the examples here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=31866&forum_id=844&group_id=256 (which I was pointed to by Arne Hennigsen, one of the authors of the "sampleSelection" package... many thanks to Arne)

I noticed that there were inequalities being used in the expressions in this code and after implementing that in my own code got matching results between Stata and R with minor rounding inconsistencies.

Comment: "You may want to also check to see how heckprob is handling the censored variables in the second equation " thats a quote from my previous post's comments. The `inequalities` you speak of are exactly what toggles the censored variables as I mentioned!!! That's how the censoring gets done!

Answer (score 2):

The R code that you provided will give the same results as Stata's heckman command: i.e.,

`heckman  ivburden  isingle recuse50 infobk2 timesurv inh icp itime igate ioth, 
select(iw5rsp= i201 isingle icatmpgte7 ichgfrwv inh icp itime igate ioth)`

One way to see this is that the output provides you with an estimate of "sigma" at the bottom. There is no "sigma" in the model that you want to estimate.

For the sampleSelection package in R to estimate the bivariate probit model with sample selection, i.e. heckprob, you first need to specify that your dependent variable for the outcome equation is a factor. Here is the fix:

```
library(sampleSelection)
ivburdenF <- factor(ivburden)
heckit(selection = iw5rsp ~ i201 + isingle + icatmpgte7 + ichgfrwv + 
              inh + icp + itime + igate + ioth, 
          outcome = ivburdenF ~ isingle + recuse50 + infobk50 + timesurv + 
              inh + icp + itime + igate + ioth, data = dat)
```

One last thing to mention is that should not use a "2 step" estimator for a Heckman-style selection model with a probit equation for the outcome.

The results of the R syntax above and Stata's heckprob should only differ due to rounding (assuming that both maximization methods achieved convergence).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for an example of how to reproduce the results of Stata's `heckprob` (alias of `heckprobit`)  with R's `heckit` function from the [`sampleSelection` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/index.html) (written by Arne Henningsen & Ott Toomet), here is a translation of [Example 1 from [R] heckprobit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rheckprobit.pdf):

```
library(sampleSelection)
library(readstata13)
library(tidyverse)

df_school = read.dta13("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/school.dta") %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  mutate_at(
    c("vote", "private"), as.factor
  )

heck_school_1 = heckit(
  selection = vote ~ years + loginc + logptax,
  outcome = private ~ years + logptax ,
  data = df_school,
  method = "ml"
)

summary(heck_school_1)
```

This should give identical results to:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/school
heckprob private years logptax, select(vote=years loginc logptax)
```

Note the need to convert the outcome variable to a `factor` and the use of `method = "ml"` in fitting the model.

Answer (score 0):

"It seems then that this package may just not do what I need it to do" -What is it you are trying to do? When you say you want a probit-probit model, do you mean you are trying to estimate a heckman style model with an outcome equation whose dependent variable is binary (bivariate probit)? The canonical heckit model uses OLS in the outcome stage, which is what the heckman function does (as opposed to the heckprob which is what you used). The problem is that R's sampleSelection package uses a function equivalent to "heckman" and not "heckprob". What you need is an R equivalent. I'm actually not familiar with one. I use a function written specifically for this task. See this link for the code: http://dynaman.net/R/HeckmanProbit.R

(Unrelated to all of this, the method of estimation can also be toggled. For the R model, you can change it to `method='ml'` or to `method='2step'` , so you may want to keep that in mind when comparing stata and R).

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, I'm trying to estimate a heckman style model in which both the selection and outcome equations have binary dependent variables. I did try toggling the methods, which didn't quite do the trick, but I'll definitely check out the link you provided. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: So after some time off I ran my model using the function provided via the link above and got results that were very dissimilar from both sampleSelection (as expected) and Stata's "heckprob" function.

Comment: What is very different? They likely use different estimation algorithms but the results shouldn't diverge substantially. You may want to also check to see how heckprob is handling the censored variables in the second equation -there might be varying options. I would try toggling all the options of heckprob to see if the results converge with the technique used in the link. Also, the link above uses STATA supplied data -why don't you use that data as a check to see if you get similar results in STATA as you do using the technique above.